# Petition for writs of certiorari to SCOTUS

Tags: data-request, legal

I'm looking for the petitions used to ask the supreme court to hear a case -- they are called petitions for writ of certiorari -- there should be about 7000 new ones generated each SCOTUS season, where about 100-200 of them are granted by the court. I don't have law school db access, and the resources available on supremecourt.gov are not comprehensive or easily available. The scotus blog has some hosted on their S3 bucket, but again there are not many.

Comment: Your question is on-topic here, but you may also try asking at law.stackexchange.com. You may also try contacting someone at the US Govt directly to ask for these (ie, via their contact links on www.gov for example). I tried searching from www.gov (which is a bit broader than supremecourt.gov) and found some useful links that weren't supremecourt.gov, though admittedly not a lot